# how to properly print each element in a c string?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char *a[20];
    FILE * fin = fopen("testtest.txt","r");
    int i;

    fscanf(fin,"%s",a);

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",a[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

In this program, I suppose to print each element in the array, which should be A B C D E
but actually it prints:

It seems every element is weired, how should I print it correctly?

```
A
E
─
╒
┴
■
┌
·
Φ

8
↔


p
╘
╠
x
3
☻
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings if you have not already done so and pay heed to them - the problems in your code would have been immediately apparent from the warnings generated when compiling the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `a` is an array of `char*`, not an array of `char`. Change to:

```
char a[20];
```

Recommend compiling at the highest warning level and treat warnings as errors. For example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:5: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Werror=format]
main.c:10:5: error: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Werror=format]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Check the result of `fopen()` and `fscanf()` to be certain the file was opened and data was read into `a` before attempting to use the variables.

Comment: He should also use `fclose`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, yes (only if the `fopen()` succeeded though).

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an array of 20 `char` *pointers*.  I think you wanted an array of 20 chars instead

```
char a[20];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[20];
FILE * fin = fopen("testtest.txt","r");
int i;

fscanf(fin,"%19s",a);
```